# SQL query much slower in app than it is run in console

Tags: sql, laravel

I have the following query in a conroller:

```
            'students' => Auth::user()->site 
                ->students()
                ->leftJoin('student_meals as m', function ($join) {
                    $join->on('m.student_id', '=', 'students.id')
                        ->where('date_served', Request::only( 'serviceDate') )
                        ->where('meal_type_id', Request::only( 'mealType'));
                    })
                ->where('enter_date', '<=',Request::only( 'serviceDate') )
                ->where('exit_date', '>=',Request::only( 'serviceDate') )
                ->OrderByName()
                ->filter(Request::only('search', 'serviceDate', 'grade', 'hr'))
                ->select('students.id as studentId', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'grade', 'hr', 'students.sfa_id as sfaId', 'students.site_id as siteId', 'sisId', 'm.id as mealId', 'm.meal_type_id', 'm.created_at as created_at', 'void')
                ->get()
                ->map(fn ($students) => [
                    'studentId' => $students->studentId,
                    'name' => $students->name,
                    'grade' => $students->grade,
                    'hr' => $students->hr,
                    'sfaId' => $students->sfaId,
                    'siteId' => $students->siteId,
                    'sisId' => $students->sisId,
                    'mealId' => $students->mealId,
                    'mealType' => $students->meal_type_id,
                    'created' => $students->created_at,
                    'voided' => $students->void
                ]),
```

That in sql translates to:

```
SELECT `students`.`id` as `studentId`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `grade`, `hr`, `students`.`sfa_id` as `sfaId`, `students`.`site_id` as `siteId`, `sisId`, `m`.`id` as `mealId`, `m`.`meal_type_id`, `m`.`created_at` as `created_at`, `void` 
FROM `students` 
left join `student_meals` as `m` on `m`.`student_id` = `students`.`id` and `date_served` = '2022-08-15' and `meal_type_id` = '2' 
WHERE `students`.`site_id` = 12 and `students`.`site_id` IS not NULL 
and `enter_date` <= '2022-08-15' and `exit_date` >= '2022-08-15' 
and `students`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
```

I have over 10 thousand records in 'students' table and over 1 million in 'student_meals'. When I run the query in Sequel Pro it completes in about 37ms,  the Clockwork developer tool shows it taking over 1 sec, which I understand it shows only the database time, not any of the processing time.

Can someone explain why?

Follow up question- would is 37ms for above query on that many records be considered good performance? Or do I need to work on it more?

---

Comment: it depends on how the data is received by the client. if it’s fetched row by row, this can take some time. especially if the client is not on the same machine as the sql server instance the data is fetched from. please tell us a) what machine is running the php code and b) which machine was the command line client running on. Also your routine processing the incoming data may be suboptimal.

Comment: It's still in development, so all are on my machine, which is a 2020 Macbook Air. I'm using sequel pro and run the query there. Clockwork is the devtool for firefox and is showing the database as taking over 1 sec. The app is only taking 76ms

Comment: `OrderByName` that’s not in the query - is that a php operation on the resultant dataset? That looks like the first of a few (slow) post-processing operations; similarly an sql query isn’t likely to significantly change execution time by using a different (db) client - I.e. that suggests the query executes in ~37ms and the time you are looking at is time in php code.